# Vertical aligning a table with a div

Tags: html, css

I have two elements, a table and a div.

```css
.LogoDiv {
  clear: both float: right;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  -moz-opacity: 0.7;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: 500px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 85%;
  background-color: #003366;
}
.Logo {
  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
  height: 84%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: 80%;
}
.SubHeadTable {
  clear: both;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  -moz-opacity: 0.7;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin-left: 15% margin-right: 15% margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #003366;
}
.SubHeadTitle {
  font-family: 'HurtMold', Fallback, sans-serif;
  color: #219c78;
  font-size: 28px;
}
.SubHeadText {
  font-family: 'Oregon', Fallback, sans-serif;
  color: 28a999;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.SubHeadTableRow {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.SubHeadTableCell {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table class="SubHeadTable">
  <tr class="SubHeadTableRow">
    <td class="SubHeadTableCell">
      <div class="SubHeadTitle">
        This is a title.
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="SubHeadText">
        This is a text which relates to the title.
        <br>It explains the title further,
        <br>And could include various other elements.
        <br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="SubHeadTableCell">
      <div class="SubHeadTitle">
        This is a title.
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="SubHeadText">
        This is a text which relates to the title.
        <br>It explains the title further,
        <br>And could include various other elements.
        <br>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="SubHeadTableRow">
    <td class="SubHeadTableCell">
      <div class="SubHeadTitle">
        This is a title.
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="SubHeadText">
        This is a text which relates to the title.
        <br>It explains the title further,
        <br>And could include various other elements.
        <br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="SubHeadTableCell">
      <div class="SubHeadTitle">
        This is a title.
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="SubHeadText">
        This is a text which relates to the title.
        <br>It explains the title further,
        <br>And could include various other elements.
        <br>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div class="LogoDiv">
  <img src="http://orig07.deviantart.net/312a/f/2010/241/c/3/my_logo_by_hamza_design-d2xjc1a.jpg" class="Logo">
</div>
```

I want to put both the div and the table in the same line, but I can't. Whenever I put one before the other in HTML, it pushes the other down, like so:

[image: The situation]

Why is that, and how do I make them align?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you use `display:inline` or `float:left` properties, the styles `margin-left: 85%;` for element `.LogoDiv`  and `margin-left: 15% margin-right: 15%` for `.SubHeadTable` must be reconsidered.

According to the css, the total width of the screen is not sufficient for both the elements. The `margin-left` for both the elements occupies 100% of the screen. Please check the [Box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) in CSS.

The CSS is also malformed.

Answer (score 1):

Just float the table to the left, and remove the first line (the one with the missing semicolon) from the CSS of the div.

```css
.LogoDiv {
  
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  -moz-opacity: 0.7;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: 500px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 85%;
  background-color: #003366;
}
.Logo {
  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
  height: 84%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: 80%;
}
.SubHeadTable {
  float:left;
  clear: both;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  -moz-opacity: 0.7;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin-left: 15% margin-right: 15% margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #003366;
}
.SubHeadTitle {
  font-family: 'HurtMold', Fallback, sans-serif;
  color: #219c78;
  font-size: 28px;
}
.SubHeadText {
  font-family: 'Oregon', Fallback, sans-serif;
  color: 28a999;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.SubHeadTableRow {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.SubHeadTableCell {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table class="SubHeadTable">
  <tr class="SubHeadTableRow">
    <td class="SubHeadTableCell">
      <div class="SubHeadTitle">
        This is a title.
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="SubHeadText">
        This is a text which relates to the title.
        <br>It explains the title further,
        <br>And could include various other elements.
        <br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="SubHeadTableCell">
      <div class="SubHeadTitle">
        This is a title.
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="SubHeadText">
        This is a text which relates to the title.
        <br>It explains the title further,
        <br>And could include various other elements.
        <br>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="SubHeadTableRow">
    <td class="SubHeadTableCell">
      <div class="SubHeadTitle">
        This is a title.
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="SubHeadText">
        This is a text which relates to the title.
        <br>It explains the title further,
        <br>And could include various other elements.
        <br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="SubHeadTableCell">
      <div class="SubHeadTitle">
        This is a title.
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="SubHeadText">
        This is a text which relates to the title.
        <br>It explains the title further,
        <br>And could include various other elements.
        <br>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div class="LogoDiv">
  <img src="http://orig07.deviantart.net/312a/f/2010/241/c/3/my_logo_by_hamza_design-d2xjc1a.jpg" class="Logo">
</div>
```

Comment: That didn't change anything. :/
Do you need any other part of the css?

Comment: Oh... In that case, you haven't described your problem too well. I thought the problem was that the table and the logo should be in the same position vertically, the table to the left and the logo to the right. In your snippet, the logo starts below the table.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused about how you want them positioned, however wrapping the table in a containing div, can help position it
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8759/)

HTML

```
<div class="tableholder">
<table class="SubHeadTable">
  <tr class="SubHeadTableRow">
    <td class="SubHeadTableCell">
      <div class="SubHeadTitle">
        This is a title.
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="SubHeadText">
        This is a text which relates to the title.
        <br>It explains the title further,
        <br>And could include various other elements.
        <br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="SubHeadTableCell">
      <div class="SubHeadTitle">
        This is a title.
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="SubHeadText">
        This is a text which relates to the title.
        <br>It explains the title further,
        <br>And could include various other elements.
        <br>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="SubHeadTableRow">
    <td class="SubHeadTableCell">
      <div class="SubHeadTitle">
        This is a title.
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="SubHeadText">
        This is a text which relates to the title.
        <br>It explains the title further,
        <br>And could include various other elements.
        <br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="SubHeadTableCell">
      <div class="SubHeadTitle">
        This is a title.
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="SubHeadText">
        This is a text which relates to the title.
        <br>It explains the title further,
        <br>And could include various other elements.
        <br>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
        </div>


<div class="LogoDiv">
  <img src="http://orig07.deviantart.net/312a/f/2010/241/c/3/my_logo_by_hamza_design-d2xjc1a.jpg" class="Logo">
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.LogoDiv {
  clear: both float: right;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  -moz-opacity: 0.7;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: 500px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 85%;
  background-color: #003366;
}
.Logo {
  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
  height: 84%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: 80%;
}
.SubHeadTable {
  clear: both;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  -moz-opacity: 0.7;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin-left: 15% margin-right: 15% margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #003366;
}
.SubHeadTitle {
  font-family: 'HurtMold', Fallback, sans-serif;
  color: #219c78;
  font-size: 28px;
}
.SubHeadText {
  font-family: 'Oregon', Fallback, sans-serif;
  color: 28a999;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.SubHeadTableRow {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.SubHeadTableCell {
  margin: 2px;
}
.tableholder{float:left;}
```

Comment: That didn't change much... but apperently my whole CSS was wrong. :/ Thank you anyway (: